# Why use `ptr::write` with arrays of `MaybeUninit`s?

Tags: rust, initialization

In the standard library, the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html#initializing-an-array-element-by-element) shows how to instantiate arrays of
`MaybeUninit`s:

```
let arr: [MaybeUninit<T>; N] =
    MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init();
```

We know this is safe because the contract of `MaybeUninit` allows for uninitialized values. Next we are asked to use `ptr::write(value)` to initialize each element. But this requires `unsafe` code once again. We also know that overwriting a `MaybeUninit` is safe, because it doesn't `drop` anything. So why not just overwrite it like `arr[i] = MaybeUninit::new(value)`?

Comment: If you use something like `MaybeUninit::<[bool; 16]>::uninit()` you should be careful to use indexing, since it will create an implicit reference to an uninitialised `bool`, which is undefined behaviour. But when all items of the array are theselves `MaybeUninit`, this should not be an issue, so I believe indexing would be safe. Have you tried [running a test case in Miri](https://www.ralfj.de/blog/2019/03/26/miri-as-rustup-component.html)?

Comment: Yes I have, see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=355167601791d5833271332369d50604 – and this gives me *some* confidence. But my use case has a generic type and I cannot check for all possible actual types. Also I use `MaybeUninit::<[MaybeUninit<T>; N]>::uninit().assume_init(), not `MaybeUninit<[T; N]>`.

Comment: I know what type you are using. I was trying to _contrast_ your code with the situation of using `MaybeUninit::<[bool; 16]>`, which wouldn't allow to use indexing. This similar case may be the reason why the documentation is written in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let arr: [MaybeUninit<T>; N] = MaybeUninit::uninit().assume_init();` is just a shortcut.

`arr[i] = MaybeUninit::new(value)`, in your example `arr[i]` is a `MaybeUninit` so your question is just about what style to use to mutate a vector. You could also do `arr[i].write(value)` that doesn't really change in practice but it's require nightly that why the doc don't use it. But you are right `arr[i] = MaybeUninit::new(value)` allow to override the value too without unsafe keyword and **it's a perfectly defined behavior**.

The thing you forget is that `MaybeUninit` is not really here to be used **only** inside Rust except very few case, Rust don't need it. We mostly use it when we dealing with ffi, so the exemple is not really a real word use case. So it can look strange. Here the author probably want to emulate a real word case where the array would be init outside Rust by using a raw pointer.

Comment: I disagree that MaybeUninit 'is not really here to be used inside Rust'. When writing custom data structures, it can be very useful. And you did not actually answer my question: Is this defined behavior?